# Why do some websites never deliver WebViewClient.onPageFinished()?

Tags: http, android-webview, webviewclient

I can understand how some sites can deliver *multiple* `WebViewClient.onPageFinished()` per page, due to having multiple iframes in that page, or having to go through multiple redirects to reach that page.

But some sites keep loading and loading... never reaching 100%, when all content is already there (with `PictureListener.onNewPicture()` already firing multiple times).

Why?

What is it that they're loading that rarely (if at all) reaches 100%?

What are the scenarios in which something like this can happen?

(slow Internet connection couldn't really explain the "never", aside from the fact that that slow connection works perfectly well for the vast majority of other sites)